# How to log only a certain exception with vavr

Tags: java, functional-programming, vavr

So I have a method which returns an Vavr `Try`:

```java
public Try<Result> request() {...}
```

`request` comes from a source which I cannot modify. Currently, I flatmap over the result from `request` and depending if the `Result` has an error return a `Try` with an exception or a success with the data from the `Result`:

```java
public Try<Data> fetchData() {
    return request().flatMap(result -> {
        if (result.hasError()) {
            return Try.failure(new FailedRequestException());
        } else {
            return Try.success(result.data());
        }
    });
}
```

What I want is in some places where `fetchData` is used first do something with the data if the `Try` is a success and if it is a failure, log an error if the error is a `FailedRequestException`, else, do something else with the exception, something like the following:

```java
fetchData().andThen(data -> ...).onFailure(ex -> {
    if (ex instanceOf FailedRequestException) {
        log.error("Could not fetch data: " + ex.getMessage());
    } else {
        // Do something with the exception
        ...
    }
});
```

My problem with this approach is that `fetchData` returns a `Try` so the caller cannot know that a `FailedRequestException` is part of the possible failures. I can let `fetchData` return a `Try<Either<FailedRequestException, Data>>` but this doesn't feel right either. Is there any way to do the above in a more elegant way? I also tried using the `Match` and `Case` but the `Case` expects a `Function` as handler and not a `Consumer`.

Answer (score 3):

To sum up: you actually have 3 scenarios (success, failure with FailedRequestException, any other failure). This sounds like a job for pattern matching! Let's make the code as visible and expressive as the business requirement :)

```
Match(fetchData()).of(
    Case($Success($()), data -> doStuff(data)),
    Case($Failure($(instanceOf(FailedRequestException.class))), fre -> logFreAndReturnValue(fre)),
    Case($Failure($()), e -> doSomethingWithOtherException(e))
);
```

FWIW, you can rewrite your `fetchData` implementation as such:

```
Try(request())
    .mapFailure(Case($(), ignored -> new FailedRequestException()))
    .map(Result::data);
```

As a rule of thumb, try to stick to using `flatMap` when the context (Success or Failure) may change. In your current `fetchData` implementation a success remains a success, a failure remains a failure, so it is a **mapping** between the input and the output, hence use `map` family of functions.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I do the suggested `Match` the type is erased and in the case for success the function expects an `Object` (the `data` in the example you gave). Also, the different `Case`s expect either a `Function`, `Supplier` or a simple return value, I want to use a `Consumer`.

Comment: No, the type is not erased, but until you correctly write the code, the compiler errors are misleading because of the poor handling of the JDK inference.

Comment: As for using a Consumer, this doesn't make sense, in functional programming, you always return a value. A Consumer returns nothing (void). What is the return type of your function? If it also returns void, then see Vavr doc: https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_the_basics_of_match_for_java section "Performing Side-Effects"

Comment: Yes, then `run` did the trick although now the code doesn't feel right anymore. Maybe I'll go look if I can refactor the code such that it doesn't need consumers. It would be nice though if vavr has a Writer monad.

Comment: Writer monad wouldn't change much for this particular matter. Even when using a Writer monad (e.g. in Haskell), your function HAS to return a value, and all branches must return a value of the same type. I think the main issue is that the Java primitive `void` and the class `Void` are different. Many functions return the primitive, which prevents returning a value in Vavr. If your functions return `Void`, it will work like a charm with Vavr, no `run` needed ;) You can easily write wrappers around your logger that return Void instead!